# Finding subspace when we know its orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis

If $Y$ is a subspace of $\ell^2$ space and $Y$ is orthogonal complement of some subspace $A$ in $\ell^2$, how to find subspace $A$?

$$Y=\{x=(x_1,0,x_2,0,x_3,0,\dotsc)\}.$$ 
I know how to find orthogonal complement but how to find subspace if we know its orthogonal complement? What should I do?

Comment: $Y$ is one-dimensional? Or what do you mean by your line $Y=\{x=...$?

Comment: x in Y is a sequenece of the form x=(x1,0,x2,0,x3,0,...) and Y is a subspace in l^2.

Comment: Given a subspace $M$, the orthogonal complement of its orthogonal complement is the closure of $M$.  So find the orthogonal complement of $Y$.